# Historic and Real-Time Data on Cardano Blockchain in csv or json format

Tags: transaction, blockchain

I am conducting some research on Cardano and would like to know if there's any historic and real-time information (on daily basis or more granular) for the below area in json or csv format:

(1) Number of wallet addresses (total unique address and active address)

**Note:** Active address means addresses that made one or more on-chain transaction(s) on a given day.

(2) Daily transaction value (in ADA and USD value)

(3) Daily number of transaction

(4) Total value staked/locked (TVL)

(5) Number of Dapps built on the blockchain

(6) Transaction fees.

(7) Number of stake pool operators

(8) Average staking return (annualized %)

(9) Block time (s) and transaction per seconds (tps)

I figured it'll be nice to have all the above metrics listed on a website so we can track the status easily. Appreciate if you can share with me if you have the sources for anyone of the above metrics. Thank you in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pull this data from the PostgreSQL database associated with DB-Sync, or GraphQL
2. Pull exchange data.
3. See 1.
4. See 1 & note that delegating stake does not lock ada.
5. Check back after the 12th of September.
6. Tx Fees currently depend on: https://docs.cardano.org/explore-cardano/fee-structure#gatsby-focus-wrapper
7. See 1
8. See 1
9. You can calculate the average values via the data in 1.
   Please have a look at https://bi.stakepoolcentral.com/ and if you have different metrics than what they offer you could reach out to them to collaborate.